# Meaning of algorithm, trees, and checks during Flann based feature matching (OpenCV, python)

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, flann

I am currently testing Flann feature matching with OpenCV in python, and do not fully understand what some of the parameters actually do. Here is a snippet of code copied from the OpenCV docs. The full code can be [found here](https://vovkos.github.io/doxyrest-showcase/opencv/sphinx_rtd_theme/page_tutorial_py_matcher.html#:%7E:text=good%20to%20go.-,import%20numpy%20as%20np,-import%20cv2%0Afrom).

```
# FLANN parameters
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
```

I am curious what the inputs `algorithm`, `trees`, and `checks` mean. The default values found in the OpenCV docs are commonly adopted by others code I have read on here, so I am therefore wondering if it is worthwhile to manipulate and test different values or if it recommended to stick with these?

- What are the key differences between the various [index parameter
  algorithms](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/383559c2285baaf3df8cf0088072d104451a30ce/modules/flann/include/opencv2/flann/defines.h#L68)?
  Why is `FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE` the most commonly used?
- I assume that `trees = 5` means that 5 KDTrees are made. What does changing this value mean in practice?
- The OpenCV docs mention that increasing the value of checks will give
  better precision but slow down the code. It says: “If you want to
  change the value, pass `search_params = dict(checks=100)`.” Is it worth
  exploring values other than 50 or 100 for checks?

And finally, aside from Brute Force Matcher and the Flann algorithms,
are there other common feature matching algorithms?